# Where is my exported nexus 5 (kitkat) contact list? How do I access it?

Tags: nexus-4, 4.3-jelly-bean, google, 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I exported my nexus 5 contact list and it said on the phone that the contact list has been exported to 'file: /storage/emulated/0/00002.vcf.', so where is this 'file: /storage/emulated/0/00002.vcf.', and how do i access(on my phone or computer) it(as a whole file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be stored in the root of your device (/sdcard).

If you plug your phone into a computer and access the phone you should see it like this: (This is on my Nexus 7 but it will appear the same)

[image: contacts on pc]

Comment: If you have a [File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=file+manager&c=apps) on your phone you should be able to access it on there as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?